# Clone a GridColumn keeping the event handlers(ClickEvents) and properties of its elements same

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, clone, eventhandler

I have an application with 4 tabs. In the first three tabs, I have some GridColumns filled with elements (Buttons, CheckBoxes, ComboBoxes, Labels etc). Each tab have different elements.

What I want to do, is to copy/clone only the selected Columns from each tab to the 4th tab, so that I could have a better modification of my data. Each cloned column must has the same functionality as its "mother".

I've managed to have the columns that I select in my "end" tab, but The elements of it don't have the same functions and eventhandlers as the original ones. How can I make the cloned columns be the same with the original ones? Is that a right way of cloning columns that I used?

I've made a simple sample of my application, to show you its format. I'm writing code in C# and WPF.

Edited XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="700">
<Grid>
    <TabControl x:Name="tabControl">
        <TabItem Header="Tab1">
            <Grid x:Name="tab1">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <StackPanel x:Name="tab1stack1" Grid.Column="0">
                    <Label x:Name="lbl1" Content="Col1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,0,10" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="txt1" Width="50" Margin="0,0,0,10" />
                    <Button x:Name="btn1" Content="Btn1" Width="50" Margin="0,0,0,10" />
                    <CheckBox x:Name="ckb1" Content="Col1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,10" />
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel x:Name="tab1stack2" Grid.Column="1">
                    <Label Content="Col2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,0,10" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="txt2" Width="50" Margin="0,0,0,10" />
                    <Button Content="Btn2" Width="50" Margin="0,0,0,10" />
                    <CheckBox Content="Col2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,10" />
                </StackPanel>
                <Grid x:Name="ao1" Grid.Column="2">
                    <Label x:Name="aol1" Content="{Binding Path=Text, ElementName=aot1}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,2,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" MouseDoubleClick="aol1_MouseDoubleClick" ToolTip="Double-Click to rename, and press Enter to apply."/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="aot1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="26" Margin="0,2,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="AnalogOut1 [Ch0]" KeyDown="aot1_KeyDown" Visibility="Hidden" LostFocus="aot1_LostFocus" />
                    <StackPanel Margin="0,30,0,0">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,10,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
                            <CheckBox x:Name="ao1enable" Content="Enable" Margin="0,0,0,10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Padding="4,0,0,0" Unchecked="ao1enable_Unchecked" />
                            <CheckBox x:Name="ao1live" Content="Live" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Padding="4,0,0,0" />
                        </StackPanel>
                        <Button x:Name="ao1kickout" Content="Kickout" Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="ao1kickout_Click" BorderBrush="Red" />
                        <Label x:Name="lb_amp1" Content="Amplitude:" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,0,0" />
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                            <TextBox x:Name="txt_an_amp1" Width="50" Height="20" BorderThickness="1,1,0,1" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" />
                            <Label Content="V" Width="25" BorderThickness="0,1,1,1" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="20" Padding="0" BorderBrush="#FFABADB3" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
                        </StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="tb_no_an_amp1" Margin="5" FontSize="10" Foreground="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                        <Label x:Name="WaveType1" Content="Wave Type:" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,0,0" />
                        <ComboBox Margin="10,0" IsReadOnly="True" IsEditable="True" Text="Please select" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
                            <ComboBoxItem x:Name="ao1wt1" Content="Sine" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="198" Selected="ao1wt1_Selected" />
                            <ComboBoxItem x:Name="ao1wt2" Content="Sawtooth" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="198" Selected="ao1wt2_Selected"/>
                            <ComboBoxItem x:Name="ao1wt3" Content="Triangle" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="198" Selected="ao1wt3_Selected"/>
                            <ComboBoxItem x:Name="ao1wt4" Content="DC Value" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="198" Selected="ao1wt4_Selected"/>
                        </ComboBox>
                        <Grid x:Name="Signal1Params" Margin="0,0,0,10" Visibility="Hidden" >
                            <StackPanel>
                                <Label x:Name="lb_ao1sp1" Content="Frequency:" Margin="0,5,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                    <TextBox x:Name="txt_ao1sp1" Text="" Width="50" Height="20" BorderThickness="1,1,0,1" Margin="0,5,0,5" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" />
                                    <Label Content="Hz" Width="25" BorderThickness="0,1,1,1" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="20" Padding="0" BorderBrush="#FFABADB3" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
                                </StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="tb_no_an_freq1" Margin="5,5,5,0" FontSize="10" Foreground="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                                <Label x:Name="lb_ao1sp2" Content="Offset:" Margin="0,5,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                                <StackPanel x:Name="ao1sp2" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                    <TextBox x:Name="txt_ao1sp2" Text="" Width="50" Height="20" BorderThickness="1,1,0,1" Margin="0,5,0,5" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" />
                                    <Label Content="deg" Width="25" BorderThickness="0,1,1,1" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="20" Padding="0" BorderBrush="#FFABADB3" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
                                </StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="tb_no_an_offset1" Margin="5,5,5,0" FontSize="10" Foreground="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                                <Label x:Name="lb_ao1sp3" Content="Bias:" Margin="0,5,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                    <TextBox x:Name="txt_ao1sp3" Text="" Width="50" Height="20" BorderThickness="1,1,0,1" Margin="0,5,0,5" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" />
                                    <Label Content="V" Width="25" BorderThickness="0,1,1,1" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="20" Padding="0" BorderBrush="#FFABADB3" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
                                </StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="tb_no_an_bias1" Margin="5,5,5,0" FontSize="10" Foreground="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                                <CheckBox x:Name="Signal_Period1" Content="One-Shot Period" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,5,0,0" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Tab2">
            <Grid x:Name="tab2">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <ComboBox x:Name="cob_Add" Height="32" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left" UseLayoutRounding="True" SelectedIndex="-1" Text="Add New Column" IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True" Margin="50,0,0,0">
                    <ComboBoxItem x:Name="cob_Add1" Selected="cob_Add1_Selected" Content="Column1" />
                    <ComboBoxItem x:Name="cob_Add2" Selected="cob_Add2_Selected" Content="Column2" />
                    <ComboBoxItem x:Name="cob_Add3" Selected="cob_Add3_Selected" Content="Column3" />
                </ComboBox>
                <ComboBox x:Name="cob_Remove" Height="32" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Right" UseLayoutRounding="True" SelectedIndex="-1" Text="Remove Column" IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True" Margin="0,0,50,0">
                    <ComboBoxItem x:Name="cob_Remove1" Selected="cob_Remove1_Selected" Content="Column1" />
                    <ComboBoxItem x:Name="cob_Remove2" Selected="cob_Remove2_Selected" Content="Column2" />
                    <ComboBoxItem x:Name="cob_Remove3" Selected="cob_Remove3_Selected" Content="Column3" />
                </ComboBox>
                <Grid x:Name="newcolumns" Grid.Row="1"/>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>       
</Grid>
```

Edited Code Behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Markup;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Xml;

namespace WpfApp1
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<DataElement> MyList { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<int> ComboBoxItems { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
        this.ComboBoxItems = new ObservableCollection<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
        this.MyList = new ObservableCollection<DataElement>();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = sender as Button;
        DataElement dataContext = btn.DataContext as DataElement;
        //tab2.Background = Brushes.Red;// do something here <------
        //btn.Click += btn1_Click;

    }

    //private void btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    //{
    //    tab2.Background = Brushes.Red;
    //}

    //private void btn2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    //{
    //    tab2.Background = Brushes.Green;
    //}

    private void cob_Add_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox cb = sender as ComboBox;
        int? comboBoxItemDataContext = cb.SelectedItem as int?;

        this.MyList.Add(new DataElement() { Label1 = "Output" + comboBoxItemDataContext.ToString(), Text1 = "", ButtonName = "btn" + comboBoxItemDataContext.ToString(), IsChecked = true });
    }

    private void aol1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        //some code
    }
    private void aot1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        //some code
    }
    private void aot1_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //some code
    }
    private void ao1enable_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //some code
    }
    private void a1_init()
    {
        //some code
    }
    private void ao1kickout_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //if (ao1enable.IsChecked == true)
        //{
        //    an1kick(); 
        //}
    }
    private void an1kick()
    {
        //a1_init();
        //some code
    }
    private void ao1wt1_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //some code
    }
    private void ao1wt2_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //some code
    }
    private void ao1wt3_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //some code
    }
    private void ao1wt4_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //some code
    }
    public class DataElement
    {
        public string Label1 { get; set; }
        public string Text1 { get; set; }
        public string ButtonName { get; set; }
        public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: cast sender into your column object then you should only need one method

Comment: I recommend to change your approach and use _DataTemplate_ing. Google it.

Comment: @Patrick Can you be more specific  about what you are talking about? I'm new to WPF and C#, and need some help. I copy the StackPanel of first Column of first Tab, which contains the controls(buttons etc). How can I "reference" to the ClickEvent of the (new)Button in the newStack(Clone), so that it will has the same ClickEvent as the Button in the original Stack?

Comment: @Ramin - Will that approach help me with the Cloning process or having the same ClickEvents and Properties of the Controls of the CopiedColumn(Stack)?

Comment: @Patrick - Moreover, I don't want to do that only for the Button, but for all the controls of the Column.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TabControl x:Name="tabControl">

            <TabItem Header="Tab2">
                <Grid x:Name="tab2">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <ComboBox 
                        x:Name="comboBox" 
                        Height="32" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                        Width="150" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                        UseLayoutRounding="True" 
                        SelectedIndex="-1" 
                        Text="Add New Column" 
                        IsEditable="True" 
                        IsReadOnly="True" 
                        Margin="50,0,0,0"
                        SelectionChanged="cob_Add_SelectionChanged"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding ComboBoxItems}"
                        />

                    <ListBox Width="400"  ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="Test">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <Label Content="{Binding Label1}" />
                                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Text1}" />
                                        <Button Content="{Binding ButtonName}" Click="Button_Click"/>
                                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>

                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Markup;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Xml;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<DataElement> MyList { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<int> ComboBoxItems { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
            this.ComboBoxItems = new ObservableCollection<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
            this.MyList = new ObservableCollection<DataElement>();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Button btn = sender as Button;
            DataElement dataContext = btn.DataContext as DataElement;
            // do something here <------
        }

        private void cob_Add_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ComboBox cb = sender as ComboBox;
            int? comboBoxItemDataContext = cb.SelectedItem as int?;

            if (comboBoxItemDataContext == 1)
            {
                this.MyList.Add(new DataElement() { Label1="1",  Text1 = "1", ButtonName = "1", IsChecked = true });
            }
            if (comboBoxItemDataContext == 2)
            {
                this.MyList.Add(new DataElement() { Label1 = "2", Text1 = "2", ButtonName = "2", IsChecked = true });
            }
            if (comboBoxItemDataContext == 3)
            {
                this.MyList.Add(new DataElement() { Label1 = "3", Text1 = "3", ButtonName = "3", IsChecked = true });
            }
        }
    }

    public class DataElement
    {
        public string Label1 { get; set; }
        public string Text1 { get; set; }
        public string ButtonName { get; set; }
        public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your help! I've edited my sample code above, and added one column as it is in my real application. As I understand, from your solution, I have to create, for each element of my column, a new element and "transfer" its properties again. Isn't it too much code? I mean that I want: 1. select, from the comboBox, which Column to copy 2. all the elements of the column have the same properties and events as the original elements, without setting again their size, clickevents etc. Maybe I didn't understand your solution correctly.

Comment: @ChrisIo You should run my solution until you figure out what its doing.  I think it will change your mind about 'transferring' properties.  Also look into UserControls.  Then you could hypothetically say Grid.Children.Add(new UserControl()) and get a new copy of your controls with the buttons hooked up